# How run an abaqus job just after another has ended?

Tags: python, abaqus

I wrote a script for create several models in abaqus and then run the jobs created using a simple python loop, but when running the script the programm runs all the jobs at the same time and the computer memory isn't enough so it aborts the jobs. I want to know how create a srcipt where the next job is submitted just after the first has ended.

Comment: It is hard to answer your question without code that shows the problem. Can you include a concise self-contained example that shows the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are invoking Abaqus. If you are creating the Abaqus processes directly you can add the `-interactive` argument to your command so it doesn't run the solver in a background process and return immediately. For example:

```
abq2018 -j my_job_name -interactive
```

On the other hand, if you are using the Abaqus API and the `Job` object to create and run jobs you can use the `waitForCompletion` method to wait until a `Job` completes. Here is the excerpt from the Abaqus documentation:

> #### waitForCompletion()
>
> This method interrupts the execution of
>   the script until the end of the analysis. If you call the
>   waitForCompletion method and the status member is neither SUBMITTED
>   nor RUNNING, Abaqus assumes the analysis has either completed or
>   aborted and returns immediately.

Here's a short example of how to create `Job` objects and use the `waitForCompletion` method:

```
from abaqus import *

# Create a Job from a Model definition
j1 = mdb.Job(name='my_job_name', model=mdb.models['my_model_name'])

# or create a Job from an existing input file
j2 = mdb.JobFromInputFile(name='my_job_name', inputFileName='my_job_name.inp')

# Submit the first job - this returns immediately
j1.submit()

# Now wait for the first job - this will block until the job completes
j1.waitForCompletion()

# Same process for the second Job
j2.submit()
j2.waitForCompletion()
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed a Graphic User Interface to improve the queueing process of Abaqus analyses.
It's available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/RemyRoux/AbaqusRunINPFiles).

Install:
1. Download or clone the package from GitHub.
2. Find the core.py file and edit the lines 31, 36, 37 and 38 according to your machine and your config.
3. Run it.

If you have any issues using it, please submit them on the GitHub repository.